# QT/Phonon Video Recording

Tags: qt, gstreamer, phonon

I want to do the Video Recording in QT Phonon media framework.Has Qt/KDE's Phonon media framework abstraction implemented Video recording? If Phonon does not implemented then how to add functionality(As Phonon uses gstreamer as backend and we can easily do Video Recording using gStreamer)

Regards

Kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Phonon only provides utilities for multimedia playback and as far as I know they do not plan to add recording functionality in the future. In order to perform video/audio stream recording you could use [QtMultimedia](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtmultimedia.html) module.